# SQL: Remove NULL Values within range

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I remove all NULL values (time gaps) between END TIME (3rd column) and the next start time (2nd column)?

Thank you!

TABLE EXAMPLE:

```
NULL    06:00:00.0000000    NULL
NULL    06:15:00.0000000    NULL
NULL    06:30:00.0000000    NULL
NULL    06:45:00.0000000    NULL
NULL    07:00:00.0000000    NULL
NULL    07:15:00.0000000    NULL
NULL    07:30:00.0000000    NULL
        07:30:00.0000000    08:30:00.0000000
NULL    07:45:00.0000000    NULL
NULL    08:00:00.0000000    NULL
NULL    08:15:00.0000000    NULL
NULL    08:30:00.0000000    NULL
        08:30:00.0000000    09:00:00.0000000
NULL    08:45:00.0000000    NULL
NULL    09:00:00.0000000    NULL
        09:00:00.0000000    09:30:00.0000000
NULL    09:15:00.0000000    NULL
NULL    09:30:00.0000000    NULL
        09:30:00.0000000    09:45:00.0000000
```

Comment: Write some code and show it to us. We are here to help you fix your stuff, not write it for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? Delete the rows? replace the NULLs with something else? Show table definition including column names and desired results.

Comment: With that sample table data, what's the expected result?

Comment: pls. add your required output which could help.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to only want to keep the initial `NULL` values.  So, something like:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.endtime is not null or
      t.endtime < (select min(t2.endtime) from t t2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this article how to obtaint previous row in sql server then check prev value and current value if it is null:
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/